# Call Method to initiate code or use event bus

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, event-bus

I'm using Broadcast Receivers to send data around to activities and fragments.
That data is either primarily for information/display purposes or to activate some code in the fragment/activity.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using an event bus to get data directly into a fragment vs just hitting a method in the fragment from the host activity to send data/activate code?

This is the non-event bus way....

```
 public class loqooBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.getAction().equals("tv.SCENE")) {
             try {
                message = (JSONObject) 
                   new JSONTokener(intent.getStringExtra("message")).nextValue();
                sceneId = message.getString("scene_sceneid");
                if (sceneId == lastSceneId){
                    return;
                }
                channel = message.getString("channel");
                args.putString("json", message.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
            lastSceneId = sceneId;
            pushToFeedFromActivity(message);
      }
```

intent is coming in from a service, which is just a json message, coming from outside.

Should I send the message from the service via event bus to its intended destination (fragments) or leave all well alone?

Comment: Some sample code would be useful here

Comment: "with an event bus, the publisher is relieved of such duties and this independence helps, because the publisher and subscriber need not have logic coded in them that establish the dependencies between the two." - http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) in a not-so-small application, and I must say it's cool. The project has different build types and flavours, and some use cases can be solved really elegantly - e.g. processing events differently in Debug and Production builds (by having different subscribers).

That's a huge plus for using events / an eventbus.

On the downside everything's pretty decoupled. While this might sound like a argument for eventbus, it's actually not always the case. It's pretty easy to make the program flow jump around seemingly randomly, and debugging can become a real pain in the neck. Refactoring is another issue - that's potentially not as straight forward as it would be without events floating around.

My advice: **Use it, but don't overuse it**. If there's a straight forward way for two collaborators to communicate prefer that. But don't decouple things that actually belong together.

Comment: ty for your thoughts. the complexity of events are right up my alley. all my apps are heavily focused on multiple fragments with multiple flavors. adding the an event bus concept to my setup is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the event bus. It makes it much easier if you later need that data in another fragment/activity, you can just subscribe to the event. It also takes care of a lot of annoying things like what if your fragment has been gc'ed already. Makes code cleaner and easier to follow as well.

Answer (score 1):

this post pretty much answers my question and guides me for the future.

http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/

almost every question I have these days comes down to one word....decoupling!